# What will be the Lorentz transformation formula for 2 frames where they do not cross each other at $t=t'=0$?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, inertial-frames

For the standard Lorentz transformation,
we assume that F' crosses F at $t=t'=0$
and is moving to the right i.e. velocity $= +v$.

In that case, we use
\begin{gathered}x'=\gamma(x-vt),
\\t'=\gamma\left(t-x\frac{v}{c^2}\right).\end{gathered}

But if we assume that F' is at distance $+d$ (in F frame) away from F at $t=t'=0$ and is moving to the LEFT i.e. velocity $= -v$.

In that case, what would be the corresponding Lorentz formula expression for $x'$ and $t'$?
Do we just add (or subtract?) $d$ (or $d/\gamma$ or $d\cdot\gamma$?) from the standard expressions?

Comment: @Frobenius Once you have learned something, it is easy to feel " why has everyone else  not learnt it. It is annoying that everyone has not learnt this simple thing. " Mathjax is not as intuitive and simple , as you think, for people who have never worked with scripts/programming languages/syntax etc. Stop trying to shame others for not being proficient in writing Mathjax

Comment: @Frobenius "_You study physics, you learn Special Relativity and you couldn't learn MathJax_ " Yes, i have studied physics, i have learnt Special Relativity AND  i have not learned MathJax. This may be  difficult for you to believe , but trust me,  people have been studying  physics and Special relativity for ages before there was anything called Mathjax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just compose a translation before/after the Lorentz transformation. To figure out how much to translate, consider that you want the event $(t,x)=(0,d)$ in $F$ to map to $(t',x')=(0,0)$ in $F'.$ Pure Lorentz transformations being linear and invertible, the only way to get $(0,0)$ from one is to put $(0,0)$ in, so if you choose to translate first just subtract $d$ from $x.$ $$\begin{gathered}x'=\gamma(x-d+vt),\\t'=\gamma\left(t+(x-d)\frac{v}{c^2}\right).\end{gathered}$$

(With $v$ in the $-x$ direction.) You can also rearrange to translate after the standard Lorentz transformation. $$\begin{gathered}x'=\gamma(x+vt)-\gamma d,\\t'=\gamma\left(t+x\frac{v}{c^2}\right)-\gamma d\frac{v}{c^2}.\end{gathered}$$ Note that the translation in this case comes from Lorentz transforming $(t,x)=(0,d)$ into $(\gamma d\frac{v}{c^2},\gamma d)$ and then translating to bring that event to the origin.

The combination of a Lorentz transformation and a translation is called a [Poincaré transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group).

Comment: Thanks, i had managed to figure out the extra term i would have to add in x'. I was struggling with the what the extra term in the expression for t' would be. One small thing, we also have to substitute -v in place of +v, in my given example, right ?

Comment: @silverrahul Oops, missed that.

Comment: Can you please also tell , how the formula would be modified further, if frame F' clock did not start synced with frame F clock . That is, in F frame, the event of t=0 was synchronous  not with t'=0 , but with t'= T (say). Would i substitute t+T or t-T in the lorentz formula ?

Comment: @silverrahul A Poincaré transform has form $x'^\mu={\Lambda^\mu}_\nu x^\nu+\alpha^\mu.$ You know ${\Lambda^\mu}_\nu$ from the velocity as a standard Lorentz transform. Plug in the $x'^\mu$ and $x^\mu$ you want to have match up and solve for $\alpha^\mu$. I.e. you can literally add/subtract whatever constants you want in the transform; all you have to do is solve for the correct constants that give a chosen event the correct coordinates in both frames.

Comment: Poincare transform is well above my level of understanding. In the case of time offset ,  Is there no simple substitution formula like we substituted x-d in place of x in case of the distance offset ?

Comment: @silverrahul No, the formula (whatever it is) is simple. It should be a simple +/- an offset either on $t$ or on $t'$. Your description was just too vague for me to tell exactly what it should be. Again: a Poincaré transform looks like just $t'=\ldots+A,x'=\ldots+B$ where the dots are the standard Lorentz transform and $A,B$ are *whatever constants you want*. Pick an event where you know the coordinate vectors $(t,x),(t',x')$ in both frames and you can figure out what $A,B$ you need to make that transformation happen.

Comment: " _Pick an event where you know the coordinate vectors (t,x),(t′,x′) in both frames and you can figure out what A,B you need to make that transformation happen._ " I had tried this, i had got A and B as complicated terms , which is why i wanted to ask about it. If you say it should be a simple +/- offset, then I may have got something wrong, which is why i wanted to know what the correct answer was

Comment: Specifically i got, for x' i simply have to substitute (t- gamma.T) in place of t , which seems simple and correct. But for t' i got , we have to substitute (t-gamma.T.(v/c)^2) in place of t, which seems not simple and hence i feel might be wrong.